# Ruby-Tire wait for indexes to get created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

Using Tire I need to fill indexes in the test cases after I create some records, which I do like this.

```
['London', 'Mumbai', 'New York'].each { |name| Place.create(name: name) }
t = Tire.index('places')
t.import(Place.all.entries)
```

How do I wait for the index to be created before proceeding?

Comment: Are you implying that `Tire.index` is asynchronous?

Comment: you can place them in the block according to the readme. Something like this should work `Tire.index 'places' { import Place.all }`.

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Yes I think `Tire.import` is asynchronous, searching immediately after it sometimes gives no result...

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Have you tried calling `t.refresh` directly after the import? It is possible that your elasticsearch index is fully updated, but Tire is out of sync with it.

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Thanks, your suggestion worked, after calling `t.refresh` I get search results everytime

Comment: I added this as an answer in case you want to resolve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `t.refresh` directly after you call `import`. This will ensure that Tire is in sync with elasticsearch.